# How do I import my Google Blogger files into Pelican without getting errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pelican

I can't import my Blogger files in the `feed.atom` file format into Pelican without some kind of Python error. I installed `BeautifulSoup4`, `lxml`, `feedparser`, and `pandoc` but I keep getting other errors appear such as the one below:

```
[root@web blog]# pelican-import --feed -m MARKUP -o /var/www/blog/content/ /home/<user>/Blogger/Blogs/test/feed.atom
WARNING: Pandoc version unknown: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pandoc': 'pandoc'
WARNING: Feeds generated without SITEURL set properly may not be valid
WARNING: No timezone information specified in the settings. Assuming your timezone is UTC for feed generation. Check http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#timezone for more information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pelican-import", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pelican/tools/pelican_import.py", line 1019, in main
    attachments=attachments or None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pelican/tools/pelican_import.py", line 780, in fields2pelican
    kind, in_markup) in fields:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pelican/tools/pelican_import.py", line 567, in feed2fields
    if hasattr(entry, 'updated_parsed') else None)
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I run a `RedHat` *derivative* if that helps any. I'm also not sure if I'm supposed to be using the `--feed` or `--blogger` parameter when making the call to parse my `feed.atom` Blogger file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug in `pelican-import`. `feedparser`'s date/time parser [returns](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/blob/2b11c8028321ed43cbaf313f83b0c94820143d66/feedparser/datetimes/rfc822.py#L118) the result of [datetime.utctimetuple()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utctimetuple) which is `time.struct_time` instance while `pelican-import` [expects](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/6f0743b340cfaa98ced38fc41727c8ea9f1a52f8/pelican/tools/pelican_import.py#L566) an object with `.strftime()` method.

Report the bug to [the Pelican tracker](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues).

Comment: The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/2498) and fixed by now. It will be released in version 4.0.2. If you need the fix already, you can clone the pelican repo and install it from sources.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know